# Html.BeginForm submit form in current window and open a new window with another URL

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, form-submit

Just to be clear at first, no it's not a some kind of spam but a request from a client it should be handled this way.

I've got an MVC project and I want to submit a form in my current window as well as opening a new window with a static URL, for example www.google.se. As it is now I have a modal that shows with the form looking like this:

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
            <div>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "controller", new { id = Model.Id }, FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    <h4>
                        Are you sure?
                    </h4>
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Yes" class="btn btn-default" />
                    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="btn btn-default">Nope</a>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
```

So I'm looking for the submission of the form to be performed on the main window and then open another window as well. That new opened window should be without toolbar or address bar.

Edit: It is not important if the window opens before or after the submission of the form as there is no validation when the form is being submitted.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add `target` on your `beginform`.

```
Html.BeginForm("Action", "controller", new { id = Model.Id }, FormMethod.Post, **new {target = "_blank"}**)
```

This will open a new tab/window.

Comment: This will handle the POST in the a new window which was not asked for in the question

Answer (score 0):

If you can use JQuery you can add handler for your submit button, this code does not prevent form submit.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").on("click", function() 
    {
       var tab = window.open(url, '_blank');
       tab.focus();
    }});
```

or put handler for your form

```
$('#openModal').submit(function(e){
           var tab = window.open(url, '_blank');
           tab.focus();
   });
});
```

Without JQuery

```
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() { 
var tab = window.open(url, '_blank');
tab.focus();
```

};

Comment: I'm afraid I can't use JQuery. But I can use JavaScript though

Comment: The order of ops here is wrong. The new window will open and *then* the form will be submitted. Based on the way the OP worded the question, the opposite is desired: the form submits, then the window opens, presumably after a successful submit. How important that is unknown, but it could be crucial depending on what's happening in that new window.

Comment: I have updated the question to clearify this but due to time restictions I haven't had time to proceed on this function.

Answer (score 0):

First, the only way to open a new window is with JavaScript. Whether or not the window has controls and chrome is also configured by that JavaScript when it creates the new window. However, bear in mind that this is ultimately controlled by the client and it can be enforced that new windows must have the buttons and chrome and even that they can't be new windows at all, but only new tabs. You ultimately have no true control over that; you can only suggest.

Second, the form post will by default cause the entire view to reload, interrupting any currently running JavaScript and preventing any yet to run JavaScript from running. That means you can't directly open a window after the POST because there's no room to do so. However, you can have the resulting new view open a new window. For example, if the post takes the user to a confirmation page, that confirmation page could have JavaScript that opens a new window.

Alternatively, you can handle the post via AJAX, which would allow you to stay on the page, and then have a new window be opened inside the success callback. However, if you're no going to use jQuery, I would suggest using some sort of library at that point, because handling a cross-browser AJAX request correctly requires a stupid amount of boilerplate code.

Comment: Is it possible to open the window before the POST as the window that does open is not dependent on the POST result?

Comment: If it's not dependent then yes. However, bear in mind, that depending on what's happening, that still may not be ideal. For example, if there's some sort of validation on the form and the user gets sent back to fix errors, the window will have already opened. Then, when they submit again, they'll get yet another new window. If the post will always be "successful", then it's probably fine to open the window first.